# Using KEYMAP to set wireframe mode one object alone

Tags: keymap

I am using blender 3.6 and i want to use key to view wireframe of only one object alone and i saw a page were an author explains it but as im new i dont know how to do it can someone help me with a step by step guide .https://blenderartists.org/t/shortcut-for-selected-objects-in-wireframe-mode/1357808/3   (LINK TO THE ARTICEL) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to go into the keymap settings to set a shortcut for that option although you will need to save the preferences to make it permanent (see below). Select an object and go to the <kbd>Object Properties</kbd> tab on the R/H sidebar. Open the <kbd>Viewport Display</kbd> dropdown.

[image]

Now right/click on the <kbd>Wireframe</kbd> entry and choose <kbd>Assign Shortcut</kbd> on the popup menu.

[image]

Type in your required shortcut key combination (I used <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-W</kbd>) and that shortcut will then toggle Wireframe view on any selected object when you're in <kbd>Object Mode</kbd>.

[image]

If you now go to <kbd>Edit > Preferences > Keymap</kbd> you will then be able to see that added entry. To make that combination permanent click the bottom-left 'hamburger' icon on that dialog and click <kbd>Save Preferences</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you verymuch

Comment: You're welcome. In fact, if you have Auto Save Preferences checked on the Preferences save menu that shortcut will be saved automatically when you exit Blender.

Comment: Noted one more question is there any way to view without solid shading activated like wireframe with x ray mode

Comment: Only on all objects in the scene by toggling into Wireframe and xray view with Shift-Z as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Okay, thank you..